# VSCODE autocompletion for express.js not showing all functions (such as use, get, post)

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, autocomplete, intellisense

```js
    console.log("Hello bots");
    const express = require("express");

    const PORT = 3000;
    const appx = express();
    const authRouter = require("./routes/auth.js");
    appx.listen(PORT, "0.0.0.0", function (){
    console.log("Connected... hi :)");
    });
    appx.u // after this dot and u it should have shown me the "use" method but it did not
    appx.g // after this dot and g it should have shown me the "get" method but it did not
```

I have npm intellisense extension installed in my vscode and I am using macos. Help me, please. Thank you in advance.

I tried doing "npm i eslint", "npm install @types/node", restarting vscode.. nothing worked!

Comment: @starball Thank you for your time.
 I don't know where is the controller that mentioned in the answer above link.

Comment: actually, the answer is in the question. install `@types/express`

Comment: @starball It worked. Thank you. Thank you so much. :)